# Can a promise be safely 'swallowed'?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm given a promise and am returning it at the end of my function for other code to do more actions after me. A kind of middleware, if you will.

```
return apiCallPromise;
```

Lets say for some reason I wish to stop those actions from happening and "swallow" a particular promise. For example by doing the following:

```
if (promiseShouldBeStopped) return new Promise((resolve) => {})
return apiCallPromise;
```

This correctly returns a promise, however it never resolves. And so the 'promise chain' has been stopped dead in its tracks.

This seems like an anti-pattern to me as it the promise is left pending forever. Are there any bad effects of this that I should be aware of, or is this a fine technique for "filtering" promises?

### Attempt to answer my own question

Does this cause memory issues?

Future code doesn't know that this promise has been filtered out, and so fails to do any "catch" or "finally" cleanup code.

- In my case this is not relevant, and I want this code to take care of those errors so that the future code doesn't have to deal with them. (this means I can guarantee that onFulfilled gives the api response, and onRejected only gives an error that is actually unexpected)

Comment: Why don't you simply resolve the promise then…? There's even a handy class method for that: `return Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: Because the promise chain will continue: the onFulfilled handlers that are added by later code will get called. This method stops those getting called, as well as the onRejected handlers (I know about this error and don't want the catch handlers to fire either!) and so I'm asking if there are any downsides to doing this. The other option would be to Promise.resolve() or Promise.reject() as you suggest, and have all following code know about this extra case and take it into account in their logic. I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking now. Regular Promises are always supposed to settle eventually. If you want *cancelable* promises, you probably explicitly want to use another library which implements explicitly cancelable promises. Simply not resolving them will… probably work…, but it certainly will pile up pending objects and callbacks, and that may or may not become an issue for you.

Comment: Ah thanks for the link to cancellable promises. It's sad that they don't exist natively yet. I'm guessing piling up the callbacks isn't an issue unless it happens a lot. I'm thinking at an API level, and so this isn't a viable solution as there's no guarantee on how often it will happen :(